# Add Class To Aura Component Based On Value From Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I would like the

```
        <div aura:id="main" style="padding:15px;" class="slds-grid">
```

to turn red if the escalation level is M2 or orange if the escalation level is M1. My Javascript is as follow. How do I get the escalation level from data.getReturnValue()

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.findCase");
    action.setParams({
        recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set("v.details", data.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers I will try them shortly. Is it possible to get the value for escalation level from data.getReturnValue(). I posted another question were this would help

Comment: if its in the data structure, yes.

Comment: How would I pull that out. It gets returned in  public static List<Case> findCase (Id recordId) {
        List<Case> details = [SELECT IsEscalated, Escalation_Level__c, Escalation_Type__c, 
        Escalation_Details__c FROM Case WHERE Id=:recordId];
        return details;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you define styles in your component's CSS style file, and conditionally apply classes - although you *can* conditionally generate the CSS itself if you really want to.

Here's what the former approach looks like, if we adapt some examples from [CSS in Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm#!) and [Conditional Expressions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_conditional.htm) to your situation:

### Component Markup

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="details" type="Map" />
    <div class="{! v.details.Escalation_Level__c == 'M2' ? 'escalated' : (v.details.Escalation_Level__c == 'M1' ? 'escalated-more' : '') }">
        Test
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

This uses a nested ternary operator to select from three choices (M1, M2, or anything else). I wouldn't generally nest any more levels as the logic becomes hard to maintain; if your logic is more complex, you could populate the desired style in a separate component attribute and update it in a change handler.

At this level, however, you don't have to write any more lines of JavaScript - it's all driven by the data you're already populating.

### Style File

```
.THIS.escalated {
    color: red;
}

.THIS.escalated-more {
    color: orange;
}
```

The `.THIS` selectors can be confusing and there's some nuance, so I recommend reading the CSS in Components documentation linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage existing SLDS classes such as the ones provided in the [alerts blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/alert/#Warning-Alert), and based on your logic, if x is returned simply use the [$A.util](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm) class methods, such as toggle to add/remove the slds class which will automatically add the èredè background to your div:

**Component.cmp**

```
<div aura:id="main" class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-theme_alert-texture slds-theme_error" role="alert">
  <span class="slds-assistive-text">error</span>
  <h2>Some redundant message</h2>
</div>
```

the class that handles the color here is `slds-theme_error`, so you can toggle it as follows in your callback:

```
 const mainCmp = cmp.find('main');
 $A.util.toggleClass(mainCmp, 'slds-theme_error');
```

the other classes are there to add texture amongst other things. so you dont really need them if all you want is a red background color.

for orange, you can use `slds-theme_warning`.